# Add reminder to page or database page

Tags: notion-api

I'm searching for a way to create a reminder to a page as a mention or in a date property of a database page.
Is there a possibility with the API yet?

In this example I want to create a new daabse entry with a reminder for the Date property.

```js
return await require("@pipedreamhq/platform").axios(this, {
  method: "POST",
    url: `https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/`,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer API_KEY_HERE`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Notion-Version": "2021-05-13"
    },
    data: {
      "parent": { "database_id": "DB_ID_HERE" },
      properties: {
        "Day": {
              "title": [
                {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": {
                    "content": "Title"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
        "Date" : { "date" : { "start": "DATE_HERE } },
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you make the question more focused by adding more information and code blocks you have tried

Answer (score 0):

The Notion API does not support reminders (or notifications for that matter) at this time.